# Confusing e-mail related to sudo

Tags: email, sudo

My system occasionally sends me this email.  (My domain has been replaced with [DOMAIN] and my username has been replaced with [USERNAME].)

```
Subject: *** SECURITY information for [DOMAIN] ***

[DOMAIN] : Jun 12 03:48:28 : [USERNAME] : unable to remove
/var/lib/sudo/[USERNAME], will reset to the Unix epoch ; 
TTY=pts/12 ; PWD=/home/[USERNAME] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=kill
```

It sends me this email about 10 times in one minute and then stops.  It's generally after I use sudo but I haven't calculated exactly when.

It feels like I'm probably configuring sudo wrong somehow, or maybe the permission of some directory or file is set incorrectly, but I don't understand the error message.

Can anyone explain this to me?

EDIT: /var/lib/sudo has owner root and permissions 700.  I belong to the group that owns /var/lib/sudo.  Within that directory (which I can't see without running sudo), the directory /var/lib/sudo/[USERNAME] has the same ownership and permissions.  That directory is empty.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37301/48232 for an explanation and the cause is probably incorrect permissions on that directory

Answer (score 0):

How are you maintaining the time on your server.  If you have a poorly running clock, then the time may need to be jumped periodically.  This may cause sudo to notice future timestamps and try to fix them.  However, I would expect different message.

If you are using `ntp` with poor conectivity or a large step setting time may jump far enough that sudo would be concerned.